# Formatting tables in PDF so that column values are not repeated for aggregate

Tags: r

I'm sorry the question title is confusing, I'm not sure how to label this problem I'm trying to solve.

I'm using the ToothGrowth dataset to produce a table that output into pdf, using the following code:

```
library(grid)
library(extraGrid)

> dput(ToothGrowth)
structure(list(len = c(4.2, 11.5, 7.3, 5.8, 6.4, 10, 11.2, 11.2, 
5.2, 7, 16.5, 16.5, 15.2, 17.3, 22.5, 17.3, 13.6, 14.5, 18.8, 
15.5, 23.6, 18.5, 33.9, 25.5, 26.4, 32.5, 26.7, 21.5, 23.3, 29.5, 
15.2, 21.5, 17.6, 9.7, 14.5, 10, 8.2, 9.4, 16.5, 9.7, 19.7, 23.3, 
23.6, 26.4, 20, 25.2, 25.8, 21.2, 14.5, 27.3, 25.5, 26.4, 22.4, 
24.5, 24.8, 30.9, 26.4, 27.3, 29.4, 23), supp = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("OJ", 
"VC"), class = "factor"), dose = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -60L))

pdf("Test1.pdf", height = 20, width = 10)
grid.table(ToothGrowth, rows = NULL, theme = ttheme_minimal())
dev.off()
```

As you can see in the output (see image below), the dose and supp column values are repeated throughout. However, I want to format the table so that the dose and supp values are not repeated throughout, I've attached another photo to show you what exactly I want.

Would appreciate some help with this, because I'm unsure if the solution lies in the data wrangling or the pdf output code.

**Existing format**
[image]

**Desired format**

[image]

Comment: Have a closer look at the R-Tag also: R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization and general computing. **Provide minimal, reproducible, representative example(s) along with the desired end result. Use dput() for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls. Do not embed pictures for data or code, use indented code blocks.** For statistics questions, use http://stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
TG1 <- ToothGrowth  # make a copy in this case, its a "build-in" dataset

inds <- duplicated(TG1[,2:3]) # use duplicated in the respective column combination

TG1[inds, 2:3] <- NA  # replace all dupe rows for your cols 2 and 3

#TG1$supp <- as.character(TG1$supp) # if you want to use "", you need to convert from factor to character first.
#TG1[inds, 2:3] <- "" # try out what works better for you.

pdf("Test1.pdf", height = 20, width = 10)
grid.table(TG1, rows = NULL, theme = ttheme_minimal())
dev.off()
```